# Issues with the UserDataFolder property for Webview2

Tags: c++, webview2

In my application, I am creating Edge environment using `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails`. Right now it is creating a folder next to my exe as `"myexe.WebView2"`, which I don't want.
So I am passing `"C:\\Users\\username>\\AppData\\Local\\MicrosoftEdge` as an `UserDataFolder`.
But still it is creating an empty folder `"Myexe.webview2"` in my application folder.

Here is sample to show how I am passing arguments.

```
HRESULT hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails(folderName, L"C:\\Users\\<myUSer>\\AppData\\Local\\MicrosoftEdge",  NULL,     Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>
```

I knew that edge creates a folder in app local folder as an default location when `NULL` is passed for `UserDataFolder`. But here I am giving location for `UserDataFolder`.

So the questions are:

- Why is it creating an empty folder with name `"myexe.WebView2"` in default location, when I am passing `"userDataFolder"`?
- What should I do to avoid that?

Update:
We have been using this version for a while. Upgrading to latest version will be done in future.
For now, the code uses `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails`.

Comment: Since  `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails` is deprecated and replaced with `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions`, perhaps you can find a solution in there?

Comment: Well, if you insist on using deprecated versions, then you must accept its limitations. Actually they have released the first non-preview version today, I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: If that is a limitation, I can accept it. I want to be sure that I am not missing any API calls or forgot to set something, which can lead to empty folder creation

Comment: Well, I have not seen it using the new version, so you may call it a bug in the old versions. Anyway, you will have to make other changes too, when you upgrade.

Comment: I just wonder, do you make sure the path you pass actually exists? Since the docs say it should have read / write. Because the browser will create a sub-folder in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is a bug. If you still see this behavior with the latest SDK, please open an issue against our [WebView2 feedback GitHub repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues) and we can look into it. Thanks!